# Cant get story going...running locally but not seeing my story locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, function, storybook

Hey I am practicing with the storybook and this is my code for my story:

```
// Button.stories.js

import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Footer1 } from './Footer1';

export default {
  title: 'Components/Footer1',
  component: Footer1,
}
```